# pgsql2shp gives different prj values for a identical copy of a postgis table

Tags: gis, postgis, arcgis

I have created two postgis tables, copied the content of one table to the other and then attempt to create a shp files of both tables.  The generated .prj should be the same as both tables have the same type of geoemtry entry, but I get different values.  Has anybody any idea what is going on ?
##My tables

countries

```
  Column  |            Type             |                        Modifiers                        
----------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------
gid       | integer                     | not null default nextval('countries_gid_seq'::regclass)
name      | character varying(80)       | 
geom      | geometry(MultiPolygon,4326) |
```

Results

```
  Column  |            Type             |                      Modifiers                       
----------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------
id        | integer                     | not null default nextval('results_id_seq'::regclass)
label     | text                        | not null
geom2     | geometry(MultiPolygon,4326) |
```

##The code
Copying result from countries to results
insert into results(label,geom2) select name as label, geom as geom2 from countries where name is not null;

##Dumping the data as shape files

```
pgsql2shp pots results -f results.shp -ggeom2
pgsql2shp pots countries -f countries.shp -gthe_geom
```

##The issue
Both tables have geomtries in the same format ie 4326 I would expect the generated prj files to be the same, but they are different
##The results
I get for countries

```
GEOGCS["WGS84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS4",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
```

For results I get

```
PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",GEOGCS["WGS       84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS   84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs"],AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"],AXIS["X",EAST],AXIS["Y",NORTH]]
```

I can read both shp files in qgis and it displays the expected results, try reading them with arcgis and there are major issues.  To the effect that the two shp files generated from the same data have different projections

What is going on?

Comment: You reference a column called the_geom, which you don't show the table information about -- just a typo?

Comment: Hi John,
it was a typo, but I tested it anyway using the correct name, it seems that pgsql2shp was clever enough to work out that if the data field does not exist, and there is an existing geometry field use that.  Thanks for note that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cracked it
Its, the arguments where in the wrong order

Used this way and the results in the correct answer

```
pgsql2shp -f results.shp -ggeom2 pots results
```